# Python host chatterbot on server

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatterbot

I want to have my chatterbot run on the server, while at the same time allow conversations to go back and forth with a user. How can I achieve this?

I was thinking using pm2 to run the bot as a service, but how can a user 'connect' to this bot at all if it is busy listening to incoming requests?

Do I need this .py module to work as a separate server along with the bot?

The following is the bot code, it's pretty much the boiler plate from the chatterbot setup guide:

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer

chatbot = ChatBot("Inssa Bot",
    logic_adapters=[
        "chatterbot.logic.MathematicalEvaluation",
        "chatterbot.logic.TimeLogicAdapter"
    ],
    input_adapter="chatterbot.input.VariableInputTypeAdapter",
    output_adapter="chatterbot.output.OutputAdapter"

    )


conversation = [
    "Hello",
    "Hi there!",
    "How are you doing?",
    "I'm doing great.",
    "That is good to hear",
    "Thank you.",
    "You're welcome."
]

chatbot.set_trainer(ListTrainer)
chatbot.train(conversation)



while True:
        try:
            say = input('Speak: ')
            bot_input = chatbot.get_response(say)
            print(bot_input)
    except(KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError, SystemExit):
        print('aaaaa')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of work to do to achieve so, here is a quick list of steps you need to follow:

1. design a web app to interact with your chatbot
2. set up a server and install your chatbot and web in it
3. train chatterbot keep server running 24/7
4. buy domain link to your site.
5. make $ ;)